# how to display javascript alert in django after Form post?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to show javascript alert with message **"No record found"**:

How can I implement:

```
 if no_record_check==0:
        alert('No record found') // here
        return render('action')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `no_record_check` as template context variable from the view. For example:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(YourViewClass, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['no_record_check'] = int(<your code>)
    return context
```

Then, in your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var no_record_check = {{ no_record_check }};  // no_record_check **must** be an integer
if (no_record_check == 0) {
    alert('No record found');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alerts are annoying show an error message instead, but you need to pass `no_record_check` in context to check later if you need to display the error message or not:

```
return render('action.html', {'no_record_check': no_record_check})
```

Then in template `action.html` (bootstrap way of displaying error bar):

```
{% if no_record_check == 0 %}
   <div class="alert alert-error">
        <strong>No Record Found</strong>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: NameError: global name 'render' is not defined:

i have already define :

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

Comment: `render_to_response` is not `render` use `from django.shortcuts import render`